# Do we need to create a UI class in Vaadin?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`SpringBoot 2`
`Vaadin 12.0.3`

```
@Route("")
public class IndexView {
```

I followed a video tutorial and the above example seems to work just fine. I don't have any `xyz extends UI` class. When I hit localhost, I see my Index View rendered.

But other recent examples I see online show something like `Main extends UI`.

Is a UI class necessary? If so, which UI should be imported. Examples show `com.vaadin.ui.UI` while the only `UI` class I see in the class path is `com.vaadin.flow.component.UI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, extending `UI` is no longer necessary in Vaadin 10+. Any component with `@Route("")` will be the root component.